# Open specific version of binary file from history

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I've got some binary files (ODT files to be specific) in my Git repository and would like to find the commit that introduced a specific change. As the compare view of Eclipse doesn't help here (it shows the binary content), I would like to download and open each version in an external editor (Libre-/OpenOffice), one after another.

I could checkout each commit, but that will take much time and is sometimes not possible from within eclipse, for example because the project layout has changed in the meantime.

I know that I can use the command line, as described here:

- [Is there a quick git command to see an old version of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338436/is-there-a-quick-git-command-to-see-an-old-version-of-a-file)
- [git - getting ALL previous version of a specific file/folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850030/git-getting-all-previous-version-of-a-specific-file-folder)

But is there any option to export a binary file from a commit *from within eclipse*?

In other words: What is the equivalent to `git cat-file -p REVISION:PATH_TOFILE` in EGit?

Comment: As a side note, may we ask why you are versioning binary files using Git?

Comment: Because I can :-) And because it belongs to the source code of my project (it contains a template for document generation). And yes I know that Git is not the best tool for handling the history of binary files, but I think that the disadvantages of using two different kind of repositories here will outnumber the advantages.

Comment: I just found out that we can switch to "FODT", which improves merges and diffs _in the future_. But I still have the ODTs _from the past_ in the history (and sometimes there are other binary files) - I mean this not an answer to my question.

Comment: Why do you want the binary file in Eclipse?

Comment: If I want to look into an earlier version of a (textual) source code file, I can just open that file from the history - and I hope there is something easy like this for binary files as well.

Comment: I upvoted your question.  While I don't see the point of looking at a raw binary file, it certainly would be useful to see an earlier version of e.g. an image binary file.