# How to save all git versions of a file to disk?

Tags: python, git, github, gitlab

Having a `file.py` which has three versions in git with three unique commit hashes.

So how can I programmatically restore all of the versions into specific files, such as:

```sh
0_<git_hash>_file.py
1_<git_hash>_file.py
2_<git_hash>_file.py
```

Solution does not have to be Python, but looking into the Python `git` package currently.

Comment: When you pull the branch you pull all of its history with it. Doing what you want should be as simple as `git checkout <git_hash> -- file1.py`. However I don't think git was designed to work back and forth like this. Is there a reason you can't create 3 branches `v1/v2/v3` and switch between them? Or use a master `file.py` to swtich between `file1/2/3` on some condition? Are other files being changed around this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
n=0
git log --pretty= --diff-filter=d --raw -- $file | 
while read m1 m2 h1 h2 rest; do
        eval git show $h2 > $((n++))_${h2}.$file
done
```

or

```
n=0
git log --pretty=%h --diff-filter=d -- $file |
while read; do
        eval git show $REPLY:$file > $((n++))_$REPLY.$file
done
```

depending on whether you want the blob's or the commit's hash in the resulting file name.

Comment: What are the `eval`s for?

Comment: @JohnKugelman To get the redirection reevaluated each time, I tried it without that and all the number prefixes came up zero.

Comment: This actually works, but it would be great to add some subfolder in the script. After execution: `ls -lh | wc -l
767` ;)

Comment: Stick a `mkdir -p content-dumps` and prefix the redirects with `content-dumps/`.  The `eval` imho shouldn't be necessary, it's a sledgehammer swatting what looks like a bug to me, split the bump in a separate stmt instead, `redirto=content-dumps/$((n++))_$h2.$file; git show $h2 > $redirto`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a specified version of a file without checking out the corresponding commit using `git show`. For example:

```
git show git_hash:./file.py
```

will print the contents of `file.py` as of the specified commit to standard output. (Presumably the Git Python interface, which I haven't used, provides similar functionality.) The leading `./` avoids path resolution problems in some cases (I don't remember the details).

I've written a Perl script that does this kind of thing for several different version control systems (most of which I no longer use): https://github.com/Keith-S-Thompson/get-versions (no warranties).

As requested, here's an example of running `get-versions` on a copy of its own repo:

```
$ ls -l
total 56
-rw-r--r-- 1 kst kst 18092 Aug  9  2015 COPYING
-rw-r--r-- 1 kst kst  6234 Apr 16  2018 README.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 kst kst   940 Apr 25  2018 TODO.md
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kst kst 20977 Apr 16  2018 get-versions
$ get-versions -pad 3 -last 3 get-versions 
$ ls -l
total 128
-rw-r--r-- 1 kst kst 18092 Aug  9  2015 COPYING
-rw-r--r-- 1 kst kst  6234 Apr 16  2018 README.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 kst kst   940 Apr 25  2018 TODO.md
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kst kst 20977 Apr 16  2018 get-versions
-r--r--r-- 1 kst kst 20752 Mar  2 10:54 get-versions,012
-r--r--r-- 1 kst kst 20766 Mar  2 10:54 get-versions,013
-r--r--r-- 1 kst kst 20977 Mar  2 10:54 get-versions,014
$
```

`get-versions -help` prints an entirely too verbose usage message. (Adding a man page is on my TODO list, as is preserving execute permissions.)

Comment: That collection looks promissing towards compability. Sadly, I am absolutly no friend of Perl, but would give it a try. Could you enrich your answer with an easy example on how to use it for the question stated here?

Answer (score 0):

Use git rev-list to get the list of commits, and git show to output the file:

```
i=0; git rev-list --abbrev-commit HEAD | 
while read sha; do
    git show $sha:./file.py > $((i++))_${sha}_file.py
done
```

This version might avoid problems with `i++` being executed in a subshell and not affecting the parent:

```
i=0; git rev-list --abbrev-commit HEAD |
while read sha; do
    git show $sha:./file.py > ${i}_${sha}_file.py
    ((i++))
done
```

Comment: This is quiet close, but outputs `0_<git_hash>_file.py
0_<git_hash>_file.py
0_<git_hash>_file.py` The files are filled but with some So it looks like the counter is not working. Furthermore, there are some fatals `fatal: Path 'file.py' exists on disk, but not in 'c6xxxx`. But that looks ok.

Comment: Increment works in bash 5.0.11.  There are plenty of ways to implement a counter. `git rev-list ... | while read s; do i=$(expr $i + 1); ... ; done` should work even in the oldest.

Comment: While playing with your command, I tried replacing `git show ...` with `echo git show ...` to get a better idea of what's going on, and ran into a bash bug. Your command (with the file name `file.py` changed to the name of a file that's in my repo) failed, treating `i` as 0 on each iteration. Changing `git ...` to `echo git ...` gave me correct file names. Then changing `echo` to `/bin/echo` gave me all 0s again. Apparently there's a bash bug involving builtin `echo` vs. external `/bin/echo`, probably affecting the scope of `$i`. Doing `((i++))` as a separate command works around the bug.

Comment: [Bug report](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2020-03/msg00000.html) and [response](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2020-03/msg00002.html). "It's not a bug. That expansion is performed as part of a redirection; redirections are performed in subshells when the simple command they affect is run in a subshell." -- Chet Ramey

Comment: @WilliamPursell Does the code in your answer work for you? I'd expect it to fail because `$((i++))` will refer to `$i` in a subshell. If you can't verify that it works, I suggest modifying the code to place `((i++))` as a separate statement. (BTW, I'm not convinced that bash's behavior is not a bug. It's at least unpleasant that builtin `echo` vs. external `/bin/echo` changes the behavior.)

Comment: @KeithThompson It works as written in bash 5.0.11(2), but does not increment `i` in 5.0.3(1).

Comment: Interesting. I'll do some experiments.

Comment: I just tried your script with bash versions 5.0.1, 5.0.2, ... up to 5.0.16, all built from source on Ubuntu 18.04. They all behave consistently, creating files `0_2dc854e_file.py`, `0_61bd5c9_file.py`, and `0_e739bdb_file.py`. It's odd that you're seeing different behavior. I'll add a revised version to your answer as an edit; please feel free to re-edit as you see fit.

Comment: Curious.  I just built from my git repo (at d894cfd104086dd) and got version `GNU bash, version 5.0.11(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19.3.0)`. ( I wish the hash was embedded in the version, and really wish it didn't include "release"!) In any case, I have no idea where the 5.0.11(2) comes from....but it works.

Comment: Just pulled and built `GNU bash, version 5.0.16(2)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19.3.0)`.  Still works. (Still confused as to why building from git gives me a "release" string in the version!)  Must be a macos thing.

Comment: I get the same `-release` suffix when I build from git on Ubuntu. i might set up a git repo with some demo scripts.

Comment: @KeithThompson FWIW, notice that bash's behaviour of doing the expansions from the redirections in the child process (when the command is an external command) is not the same in all the shells: `[shell] -c 'a=1; /bin/true >/tmp/$((a=2)); echo $a'` will only print `1` in bash, zsh and the defunct ksh2020 (but not in ksh93).

Comment: Evaluating command arguments in the main shell process but redirection arguments in the forked command-execution process seems like a pretty clear POLA violation to me. That's not a "subshell" in the usual meaning of the word.  Command arguments are actually passed to the invoked command by the same forked process that does the redirections, so saying one set should be evaluated in the forking process and one in the execve'ing process seems to me to require an explanation.